Davening and learning when emotionally distressed
In similar but slightly different light to this question: If one is mentally drained, should a person still daven? Even if that person cannot concentrate?
What is the halacha for one who is very angry, or very upset, or very emotionally shaken? Should they daven? There are sources that state otherwise, but I have heard in the past that they may not apply now, due to our lowly generation who doesn't guarantee concentration in any circumstances anyway.
Should one learn? Perhaps the study will help calm him down?
To avoid simple answers like "stop being angry", lets say that it's a situation where the distress is beyond a person's current "level" of self control, and they can't quickly calm down at the moment. They can try harder in future to improve their self control, but now is not the time for that.

Again, I think questions that start with "Should one..."  must be directed to a personal rabbi, as this is very personal, and your rabbi knows you best. Instead it is worth phrasing in a more neutral form, like "What are different approaches to davening in distress?".

There's Lifne Iver we should worry about. This is why this site does not aim at personal recommendations. Your question is very personal and very loaded, so it is worth phrasing it in a more neutral form so newcomers would not stumble on its answers.

@AlBerko I don't see it that way. It's a very practical question (about emotional situations, but the question itself isn't emotional). Not going to insist though. I just want to be convinced, ideally by some meta post or stronger argument? I never said it applies to me, there's no reason to believe that. See my edit. If  still not good enough, may I recommend, to be fair, you also suggest the quoted question also be closed, or at least explain to me how I can improve it to match its level of "non lifnei iver" according to your reckoning

@AlBerko btw, how do you understand lifne iver? According to scripture, it literally means don't trip up blind people. Why do you agree with the sages on their interpretation on it?

Well, I feel it in my bones. People [and like I was, and like you sometimes post] study with particular rabbis who fail to mention that their Psakim do not cover the variety of Judaism. Then they go online and post, while suffering from confirmation bias (picking only the sources that support their views) and being absolutely sure that they speak the final truth about Judaism. I know that I hurt several people and was hurt myself. Therefore (following @doubleAA's advice) I try my best to reflect this complexity in my questions and answers.

@AlBerko sounds like a very complex thing to deal with. Hatzlacha.

@AlBerko and RabbiKaii Questions that are asking for personal guidance are out-of-scope per https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic . There's an adjacent grey area of questions that look a lot like the intent is to get personal guidance, though they are formally in third person. We've had a bunch of discussion about those in Meta, e.g. https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2125 and https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3760 (and follow links from there). This post doesn't look like that at all to me. (1/2)

That said, an answer along the lines of "The right approach to this would be highly dependent on the nature of the individual asking, as indicated by this source and this rabbi story." could be a legitimate response (2/2)

@IsaacMoses and I indeed would accept such an answer if it met my other expectations. That criteria would not affect my decision.
